# Schlegel diagram of polytope

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-geometry

I'm currently studying polytopes and using the book [Lectures in Geometric Combinatorics](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=STML-33) by Thomas. When I come to [Schlegel diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlegel_diagram), I do not quite understand how to determine whether a Schlegel diagram is a Schlegel diagram. In the book on p. 34, it states that if $\mathcal{D}$ is indeed a Schlegel diagram, then $\mathcal{D}$ is a regular subdivision of $|\mathcal{D}|$, the support of $\mathcal{D}$. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Ed pegs description is good and complex

Answer (score 1):

Page 34 of "Lectures in Geometric Combinatorics" gives a diagram of a non-Schegel diagram. Not a very intuitive description, is it?  You'll likely find the following explanation more useful:

[Definition of regular subdivisions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30981/definition-of-and-intuition-for-regular-subdivisions-of-a-polytope)